# File In/Out, Program crashes after case 1 is invoked

Tags: c++, file-io, runtime-error

I have been using stack overflow for a while now to get through my first c++ class and this is my first time asking a question, so please bear with me. 
This problem is about file in/out - simple reading and writing. I am supposed to crunch through a no frills text file and determine whether a string has leading or trailing punctuation, split them off, count punctuation and letters (not punct in the middle of strings as in the word can't or www.google.com)
I have the loops down (or so I thought) but recently my program crashes every time I invoke case 1 of the main switch statement to select a file to in. Case 1 does the primary crunching to determine the longest string, shortest string, punct count , and letter count.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream in;
ofstream out;
char outFile[50], inFile[50];
string temp, wird;
int x, longest, shortest, words, punct, wordlen, length, count;
float letters;


cout << "Enter output file: ";
cin >> outFile;
out.open(outFile);
do{
   cout << "\nSelect an option:\n\t1 - Enter input file name\n\t2 - Determine word statistics\n\t3 - List shortest words\n\t4 - List longest words\n\t5 - Search for a word\n\t6 - Exit\n";
   cin >> x;
   switch(x){
             case 1: // input file select
                  cout << "\nEnter input file name: ";
                  out << "\nEnter input file name: ";
                  cin >> inFile;
                  in.open(inFile);
                  words = 0;
                  letters = 0;
                  punct = 0;

                  in >> temp;
                  longest = temp.length();
                  shortest = temp.length();
                  do{ // to determine letters, words, longest, shortest, punct
                           length = temp.length();
                           if (ispunct(temp[length -1]))
                                   {
                                      punct++;
                                      temp.erase(temp.end()); // erase trailing punct
                                   } //end if
                           if( ispunct(temp[0]))
                                   {
                                       punct++;
                                       temp.erase(temp.begin()); // erase leading punct
                                   } // end if
                           length = temp.length();
                           if(length > 0)
                           {
                              words++;
                              letters += length;
                              if(longest < length)
                                         longest = length;
                              if(shortest > length)
                                          shortest = length;
                           } // end if nest                                                                                                      
                           in >> temp;
                  }while(in);


                  in.close();
                  in.open(inFile);

                  break;
             case 2: // file stats
                  if(!in.is_open()){
                                    cout << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    out << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    } // end if
                  else {
                       cout << "\nFilename: " << inFile <<
                       "\nTotal number of words: " << words <<
                       "\nAverage word length: " << letters / words <<
                       "\nTotal number of word characters: " <<  letters <<
                       "\nTotal number of punctuation characters: " << punct<<
                       "\nShortest word length: " << shortest <<
                       "\nLongest word length: " << longest;
                       out << "\nFilename: " << inFile << 
                       "\nTotal number of words: " << words <<
                       "\nAverage word length: " << letters / words <<
                       "\nTotal number of word characters: " <<  letters <<
                       "\nTotal number of punctuation characters: " << punct <<
                       "\nShortest word length: " << shortest <<
                       "\nLongest word length: " << longest;
                       } // end else
                  break;
             case 3: // shortest words list
                  if(!in.is_open()){
                                    cout << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    out << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    } // end if
                  else{
                  cout << "Filename: " << inFile << "\nShortest words in file:\n";
                  out << "Filename: " << inFile << "\nShortest words in file:\n";
                  in >> temp;
                  do{ 
                           length = temp.length();
                           if (ispunct(temp[length -1]))
                                   {
                                      punct++;
                                      temp.erase(temp.end()); // erase trailing punct
                                   } //end if
                           if( ispunct(temp[0]))
                                   {
                                       punct++;
                                       temp.erase(temp.begin()); // erase leading punct
                                   } // end if
                           length = temp.length();
                           if(shortest == length){
                                      cout << temp << endl;
                                      out << temp << endl;  
                                      }//endif                                                                            
                           in >> temp;
                  }while(in);
                  }//endelse
                  in.close();
                  in.open(inFile);

                  break;
             case 4: // longest words list
                  if(!in.is_open()){
                                    cout << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    out << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    } // end if
                  else {
                  in >> temp;
                  do{ 
                           length = temp.length();
                           if (ispunct(temp[length -1]))
                                   {
                                      punct++;
                                      temp.erase(temp.end()); // erase trailing punct
                                   } //end if
                           if( ispunct(temp[0]))
                                   {
                                       punct++;
                                       temp.erase(temp.begin()); // erase leading punct
                                   } // end if
                           length = temp.length();
                           if(longest == length){
                                      cout << temp << endl;
                                      out << temp << endl;  
                                      }//endif                                                                            
                           in >> temp;
                  }while(in);
                  in.close();
                  in.open(inFile);
                       }// end else
                  break;
             case 5:
                  if(!in.is_open()){
                                    cout << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    out << "\nError - no input file selected";
                                    } // end if
                  cout << "\nEnter word to find in file: ";
                  out << "\nEnter word to find in file: ";
                  cin >> wird;
                  cout << "\nWord to find: " << wird << endl;
                  out << "\nWord to find: " << wird << endl;
                  count = 0;
                  in >> temp;
                  do{
                           length = temp.length();
                           if (ispunct(temp[length -1]))
                                   {
                                      punct++;
                                      temp.erase(temp.end()); // erase trailing punct
                                   } //end if
                           if( ispunct(temp[0]))
                                   {
                                       punct++;
                                       temp.erase(temp.begin()); // erase leading punct
                                   } // end if
                           length = temp.length();
                           length = temp.length();
                           if(temp.compare(wird)){
                                      count ++ ; 
                                      }//endif                                                                            
                           in >> temp;
                  }while(in);
                  in.close();
                  in.open(inFile);



                  cout << "\nThe word " << wird << " appears " << count << " times.";
                  out << "\nThe word " << wird << " appears " << count << " times.";
                  break;
             case 6:
                  in.close();
                  out << "\n Program terminated by user";
                  out.close();
                  break;} // end switch
   }while(x < 6);
return 0;    
} // end main
```

Comment: Compiles and runs for me. I was not able to crash it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where in case 1 does it crash (debug it to find out)? Also please read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to write MCVE code when asking a question here.

Comment: I'm using dev c++ and windows 7 do you know of any issue that could be on my end?  My response to John Odom :  an access violation (segmentation fault) raised in my program.

Comment: Your loops only seem to do something on the first index and the last index, so they don't need to be loops.

Comment: To elaborate on @JohnOdom's comment: you said *"my program crashes every time I invoke case 1 of the main switch statement to select a file to in"* .  Okay, so why do we need to see cases 2 through 6?  In addition to reading the MCVE link, I'd suggest reading fully through [Short, Self-Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/).  You need to do the work to remove the extraneous code and might just find the smoking gun while doing so.  (Note you can edit your questions with the EDIT button.)

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is this dangerous combination:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

In combination with

```
temp.erase(temp.begin());
```

...which shortens your string.

This means that if a string in the input starts with punctuation, the following statement will peek one beyond the end of the string:

```
if ( i == (length - 1) && ispunct(temp[i]))
```

All of this while, as @molbdnilo stated, you don't even need loops in this case.